# there some syntax error that my vs code shows which uses hintrc file to remove them

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

[css ask for same solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgaii.png). [this picture shows the quick fix by hintrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG647.png). [this is css file with ask for same fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAl9q.png). why does my vs code give these two option, one is disable meta-viewport' hints in this project and another one is edit.hintrc for current project in my html code.

The code is running fine as before without those syntax error but these small syntax error came from nowhere [html and css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kVch.png)

I want to get my code running without using a hintrc file.

Comment: I don't see it. where in the screenshots you're showing is "hintrc" mentioned?

Comment: can you check again . thanks

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it. Did you install any extensions related to [webhint](https://webhint.io/)? If so, was that intentional?

Comment: yes it was the Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code extension. thanks for the solution

Comment: so you don't need/want that extension?

Comment: i don't think so, because everything working just fine as before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asker found by doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) that the undesired behaviour was coming from [the Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/microsoft-edge-devtools-extension) (actually, that's pretty clear from the screenshots), and that they considered it a solution to just disable / uninstall that extension.